# Solving Minimization problem with Ortools in python

Tags: python, minimize, or-tools

I am trying to solve the minimization problem.

But the results keep giving me zeros.

Are the constrains which I set are wrong or the codes are wrong?

Objective funct:

****M = 80x+60y+55z****

Constrants:

****1. 4x+2z<=20****

****2. 4y+z<=15****

****3. x+y+z<=30****

****4. 0.215x+0.04y+0.367z=0.3(x+y+z)****

I don't have much knowledge in using Ortools but I wrote these:

## Create the linear solver with the GLOP backend.

solver = pywraplp.Solver('main',pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

## Create the variables xyz.

```
x = solver.IntVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), 'x')

y = solver.IntVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), 'y')

z = solver.IntVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), 'z')
```

## Setting constraints: (only showing as the rest are similar)

Case:**4x+2z<=20**

```
constraint0 = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 20)

constraint0.SetCoefficient(x, 4)

constraint0.SetCoefficient(z, 2)
```

## Setting constraints: (setting the final constraint)

Case: **0.215x+0.04y+0.367z=0.3(x+y+z)**

```
constraint3 = solver.Constraint(0,-solver.infinity())

constraint3.SetCoefficient(x,-0.0850)

constraint3.SetCoefficient(y,-0.26)

constraint3.SetCoefficient(z,0.067)
```

## Create an objective function

**M = 80x+60y+55z**

```
objective = solver.Objective()

objective.SetCoefficient(x, 80)

objective.SetCoefficient(y, 60)

objective.SetCoefficient(z, 55)

objective.SetMinimization()
```

## At last, solve the equations and output the results

```
solver.Solve()

print('Objective value =', objective.Value())

print('x =', x.solution_value())

print('y =', y.solution_value())

print('z =', z.solution_value())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 points:

- You are making a common mistake, you are confusing a MIP solver and a LP solver. Please use CBC, SCIP, or CP_SAT as the backend.
- 0 seems to be the optimal value for all variables.
- you can use the *natural* API: `model.Add(4* x + 2* z <= 20)`

Comment: -thank you for the comment


-i changed to "pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING" to do the solving


-it seems that the constraints I set for the problems are wrong so that zeros are output